# HtmlUnit getpage extreme slow with javascript enabled

Tags: htmlunit

Buddies

I am using HtmlUnit to do some automatic login an data checking job.

When targeting at this url, the getPage function takes about 5 minutes or event more to return the result when set JS enabled. But it only cost no more than 3 seconds to get the page while using Chrome. I need to keep JS enabled since some login logic relies on it. Can anyone gives any suggestions?

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)
    webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(1*1000)
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1*1000)
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true) 
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false) 
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false)
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false) 
    HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://etrade.efunds.com.cn/etrading/etrading_orga.jsp")
```

Comment: I find that it may be caused by a complex js 100001.https.js, is it possible to skip the execution of this specific js file?

Comment: find a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482544/can-i-configure-htmlunit-to-only-run-specific-javascript-processes-and-not-the-w